# How to set field value for WebPart Properties

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, jsom

Trying to use JSOM to update an existing ContentEditor on my SharePoint,
I want to set a field value "WebUrl"  to search another list item

```
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
      function()
        {
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var pageFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/Insight/fr-fr/ad/Pages/dm1A.aspx");
var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartDef = webPartManager.get_webParts().getById('996f8bd0-c26d-4774-9a39-e72c1cfa37d2');
var newSource = '~sitecollection/en-us/pms/';
var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
ctx.load(webPart,'Properties');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function () {
    var properties = webPart.get_properties();
    console.log(properties.get_fieldValues()['Title']);
    console.log(properties.get_fieldValues()['WebUrl']);
    properties.set_item("WebUrl", '~sitecollection/en-us/pms/');
    properties["WebUrl"] = "~sitecollection/en-us/pms/";
    webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
  },
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  });

        }, "sp.js");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to fix issue :
Add line : `ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {}, function () {});`

Code:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
      function()
        {
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var pageFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/sight/fr-fr/ad/Pages/1A.aspx");
var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webPartDef = webPartManager.get_webParts().getById('996f8bd0-c26d-4774-9a39-e72c1cfa37d2');
var jsLinkUrl = '~sitecollection/en-us/ps/';
var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
ctx.load(webPart,'Properties');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function () {
    var properties = webPart.get_properties();
    console.log(properties.get_fieldValues()['Title']);
    console.log(properties.get_fieldValues()['WebUrl']);

      var urlS = properties.get_fieldValues()['WebUrl'];

      console.log(urlS);

    properties.set_item("WebUrl", '~sitecollection/ps/en-us/');
    //properties["WebUrl"] = "~sitecollection/en-us/ps/";
    webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {}, function () {}); // Add execute query

  },
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  });

        }, "sp.js");
```

Enjoy